# Delete array from 2D array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a 2D array like this:

```
 [array([71, 35, 44,  0])
 array([56, 55,  0])
 array([32, 90, 11])
 array([ 0,  3, 81,  9, 20])
 array([0, 0]) array([0, 0]) array([0, 0]) array([ 5, 89])]
```

and I want to remove `[0, 0]`

I try to

`myarray = np.delete(myarray, np.where(myarray == [0, 0]), axis=0)`

but it doesnt work.

How can I remove `[0, 0]` ?

Comment: Are you wanting to remove all elements from your list of arrays that are equal to `array([0, 0])`?

Comment: I would like to remove all array([0, 0])

Comment: That's not a 2d array.  It's a 1d array of objects (pointers), which happen to be arrays of varying length.  You might has well think of it as a list of arrays.

Answer (score 3):

Use a list comprehension with [`np.array_equal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array_equal.html):

```
>>> [i for i in arr if not np.array_equal(i, [0,0])]
```

```
[array([71, 35, 44,  0]),
 array([56, 55,  0]),
 array([32, 90, 11]),
 array([ 0,  3, 81,  9, 20]),
 array([ 5, 89])]
```

However, it is best to not work with jagged numpy arrays, as numpy does not behave well with such arrays.

Comment: I store them like this: np.array([np.array([1, 2, 3]), np.array([4, 5])]).
I thought this would make an array of arrays of numpy type

Comment: Numpy doesn't handle jagged arrays either.

Answer (score 1):

If you have numpy array to delete first row of a 2d array:
insert `axis=0` to remove rows and `axis=1` to remove columns

```
array2d=np.delete(array2d, 0, axis=0)
```